# Trying to setup Querydsl 3.6.0 with MongoDB, but MorphiaAnnotationProcessor is not found

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, querydsl

I have a small example project for mongodb and can't get the annotation processor to work.  I am using the examples from:

http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s07.html

Running `mvn clean install` produces:

```
Annotation processor 'com.querydsl.mongodb.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor' not found
```

I have been all over the place looking for that processor.  Just can't find it.  Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.stevesando</groupId>
<artifactId>FindAll</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.mongodb.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct classname is `com.mysema.query.apt.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor`

Comment: Thanks! FWIW I needed org.mongodb.morphia as well, to get the annotations to work.

Comment: Yes, in querydsl-mongodb it's only an optional dependency.

Answer (score 12):

Using Spring Data, you should use **`org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor`**

> Spring Data Mongo provides a custom APT processor to generate the
>   Metamodels instead of the one provided in QueryDSL, it will scan the
>   Spring specific @Document instead of the Morphia specific annotations.